# Issues with Drop Down Menu size and overlap CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble with my drop down menu,  the second level items overlap each other and each item has a different width.  I have searched this site and tried fixes to similar problems, but haven found anything that works.  I am not a programer, but am trying to add this to my website.  Here is my code:

```css
#menu ul,
#menu li,
#menu span,
#menu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}


#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
position: absolute;
top: 1.1em;
}

#menu
{
position: relative;
background: #171e35 url('images/menubg.gif') repeat-x top left;
height: 3.5em;
padding: 0em 1.0em 0em 1.0em;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menu ul > ul > li
{
float: left;
}


#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;  
  *width: 100%; /* IE7 hack*/
}
#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu:after,
#menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


#menu ul li
{
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a
{
padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.9em 1.0em;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*#menu ul li a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
}*/

#menu ul li a.active
{
background: #171e35 url('images/menuactive.gif') repeat-x top 

left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Menu</title>
<!-- zenlike1.0 by nodethirtythree design http://www.nodethirtythree.com -->
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu"><!-- HINT: Set the class of any menu link below to "active" to make it appear active -->
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Department</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Patrol </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Investigations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Records </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Prosecution
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Forms</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Media</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u69wpwoe/)

Created a class `submenu` and added `display:block`. This allows us to assign a `width` and `height` value DOM objects and stops your menu items from overlapping. In your case I assigned the class `submenu` to the malfunctioning menu items to avoid any conflicts with preexisting code.

[Simplified version fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u69wpwoe/1/)

Since you're not a programmer I took the liberty to polish up your code and remove the lines that weren't doing anything. The `simplified` link above has the same functionality as your code (with solution) but with less confusing classes. It may make it easier for you to continue working on your site!

To fix alignment on your website, replace the CSS for `ul#menu ul` with:

```
ul#menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

To address the submenu appearing behind your content add `z-index:10` to `#menu`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your solution solved the crowding issue, but when I added the menu back to the full website, the child items don't lline up under the parent.  It is also showing behind other items on the page.  Here is a link to the website so you can see http://www.greenlandpd.us/WorkingWebsite.html

Comment: The child items also disappear when the mouse moves off the parent item.  I'm not sure if I should post the entire css & html codes here.

Comment: This solution doesn't address the gap between the main nav and child items. Add some padding-bottom to the main nav item to fix this issue. I've addressed this problem in my answer to your question. Good luck.

Comment: @DawnSawyer I've edited the solution to include your new points

Comment: The children disappear because there is a gap between parent and child. There is a moment where none of the `hover` CSS executes. @mbnyc has the right approach to fixing it, simply ensure the child and parent are physically connected.

Comment: @Alexei Darmin and mbnyc  It worked, thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Give the sub nav links more `line-height`.

Add this rule to your styles:

```
#menu ul li ul li {
    line-height: 2em;
    }
```

Then, to close the gap created between the main nav and the sub nav (which will prevent you from hovering over sub nav links) add a bit of `padding-bottom` to your existing main nav rule:

Adjust this rule in your styles:

```
#menu ul li a
{
    /* original */
    /* padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.9em 1.0em; */

    /* new */
    padding: 0.5em 1.0em 1.1em 1.0em;

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The solution above is a straight answer to your question and solves the problem you raise.

However, I would suggest you consider a better overall solution for your navigation development. Currently, it seems a bit disjointed and patched together.

Here's a great video tutorial for building clean, elegant and robust nav menus.
https://youtu.be/k14bxM1cWoM?list=PLl1MmKpV0eieAACJx-rTMnmKYfcBOjqKN

Answer (score 0):

Try this style,

```
<style>

#menu {
position: relative;
background: #171e35 url('images/menubg.gif') repeat-x top left;
height: 3.5em;
padding: 0em 1.0em 0em 1.0em;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
margin-right: 1px;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
padding: 0px 30px;
line-height: 45px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #171e35;
}

#menu .active{
background: #171e35;
}

#menu li{
position: relative;
}

#menu ul ul{
position:absolute;
left: 0;
display: none;
width: 300px;
}

#menu li li{
float:none;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
display:block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css on your style

```
#menu ul ul li a {
    width:100%;
    float:left
}
```